# About pointers and ASCII code

Tags: pointers, ascii

im learning more about c language and i have 1 doubt about 1 code that i have seen.

```
main(){
    int i = (65*256+66)*256+67;

    int* pi; 
    char* pc;

    pi = &i; 

    pc = (char*)pi; 

    printf("%c %c %c \n", *pc, *(pc+1), *(pc+2));

}
```

Output is: C B A

I know that ASCII code of A is 65, B is 66, and C is 67 but the variable i is none of them.
If i put variable i=65, the output is just A and dont show B or C, why?

And i would like to know why this code have that output. Thanks for any help.

Comment: how are pointers and ASCII related?

Comment: maybe it has not much to do with ascii but it's a very good snippet to demonstrate how pointer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
int i = (65*256+66)*256+67;
```

turns i into the following

```
00000000 01000001 01000010 01000011
```

int = 4 bytes or 4 groups of 8 bits

char = 1 byte or 1 group of 8 bits.

What happens is that a char pointer is used to point to a subset of the original int bits.

At first the pointer points to the 8 least significant bits (the group to the right). 
And the letter C is printed. Then, the pointer it self is incremented by 1 which makes it point to the next group of 8 bits in the memory which happens to be B. And once more for the A.

Answer (score 0):

*256 means left shift by 8 bit (1 byte) so the line

> int i = (65*256+66)*256+67;

actually put A,B,C on 3 adjacent bytes in memory

then pi pointer made point to the address of integer i, then same address down cast to char pointer pc, so pc actually hold the address to a byte that contains 'A', and of course if you add 1 and 2 to the address that means the adjacent 'B' and 'C' get pointed to and print out.

EDIT: just to clarify a bit more int is 32 bit long but char is 8 bit, that's why u need a char pointer to represent an address valid for 8 bit long.

Answer (score 0):

Characters are stored as bytes, as you probably know. The initializing of the variable 'i' has the following meaning:

```
65*256 // store 65 ('A') and left shift it by 8 byte (= '*256')
(65*256+66)*256 // add 66 ('B') and shift the whole thing again
(65*256+66)*256+67 // add 67 ('C')
```

'pi' is initialized as a INT pointer to 'i'
'pc' is initialized as a CHAR pointer to 'pi'
So 'pc' then holds the address of the beginning of the 3 bytes stored in 'i', which holds 'A'.
By adding 1 and 2 to the address in pc, you get the second and third bytes (containing 'B' and 'C'), as follows:

```
printf("%c %c %c \n", *pc, *(pc+1), *(pc+2));
```

Working on the bits here ;D